# What are the advantages of using authentication alias in data sources?

Tags: authentication, encryption, encoding, datasource, websphere-liberty

When I add a data source that contain the `user` and `password` properties in the `server.xml` in [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/)

Example:

```
<dataSource jdbcDriverRef="db2-driver" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
  <properties.db2.jcc user="MyUser" password="MyPassword"
                databaseName="dbName" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50000"/>
</dataSource>
```

I get the following warning in the logs:

```
J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name 
           and password on dataSource[default-0].
```

Looking at how to do this in [Configuring authentication aliases for the Liberty profile](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_sec_jca.html) I see them put the `user` and `password` in another element called `authData` like this:

```
<authData id="auth1" user="MyUser" password="MyPassword"/>
```

I don't get what advantage moving the user name and password from the `dataSource` element to the `authData` element is giving me. In both cases the password is showing in plain text in the `server.xml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere Liberty uses an adapter to manage it's database connections.  By specifying an authentication alias the password used by the adapter will be encrypted.  If you do not use an auth alias, the userID and password will get stored without encryption on adapter properties.

Additionally, aliases provide another layer of abstraction since the aliases themselves are a resource.  The benefit here is that the alias can be configured independently if the database user/password needs to be changed and there are many datasources configured, they can all point to the same auth data.

Use the `securityUtility encode` command in the wlp/bin directory to encode the password in your server.xml.

Answer (score 2):

If you add authentication data via WebSphere Developer Tools (WDT), you will be prompted during setting password to encode (xor) /encrypt (aes) it. And it will be saved in `server.xml` for example like that:

```
<authData user="user" password="{xor}Lz4sLCgwLTs="></authData>
```

Comment: The xor/aes string can also be applied directly in datasource properties, it doesn't only work inside the <authData> element.   Could the tooling be improved to prompt for encoding/encryption when setting a password on datasource properties as well?